# Read quotation mark within quoted text in R

Tags: r, fread, read.table

I am trying to read the following text into R:

```
    "Complete","2014 H2","123456","Local","789123","File of files","A","142","000","Text",""Sharp Yield Rise
    -3.7%
    Flight to Quality
    -5.6%
    Liquidity Crisis
    -11.1%
    Equity Crash
    -2.5%
    Credit Crisis
    -9.7%""^M
```

The input file is a [CMA](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SS9RXT_10.2.2/com.ibm.swg.ba.cognos.ctm1.doc/welcome.html) file (IBM Cognos).

I run the following code.

```r
a <- read.table("aa.cma", header=FALSE, sep=",", stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
```

I get the following error:

```
Error in scan(file = file, what = what, sep = sep, quote = quote, dec = dec,  : 
line xxx did not have 11 elements
```

The `line xxx` reference is for the **`-3.7%`** line from above.

I think this is either due to the quotation mark within the quoted text (see **"Sharp"** in text above) or having embedded sep=',' and/or (unescaped) '\n' characters within unbalanced unescaped quotes.

Your help is very much appreciated.

Comment: Can you link to the exact file?

Comment: `read.table` is trying to read a dataset that has entries separated by `","` as specified by the `sep` argument. It encounters an error, since only the first line has commas and thus the rest of the observations do not exist. If you want to read it as a table and fill missings, try to add the argument `fill = NA`, except I doubt this is the output you want. How exactly do you expect the output to be?

Comment: Thanks Therkel. The output is to be 11 variables. In this example The **last variable** is to be: -3.7%
    Flight to Quality
    -5.6%
    Liquidity Crisis
    -11.1%
    Equity Crash
    -2.5%
    Credit Crisis
    -9.7%

Comment: The last variable is the problematic one. It is a text variable and it can contain quotes, commas, etc. It is commentary written by users.

Answer (score 0):

read_csv from dplyr seems to do the trick (Read strings that contain a quote in a comma-separated and quote-contained files. For instance, "a","b","c"" where the values are a, b and c")